# Where was Nunnally between the end of the Black Rebellion and her appointment as Viceroy of Area 11?

Tags: code-geass

During the Black Rebellion we see V.V enter Ashford Academy to see Nunnally. shortly after, while Lelouch is interrogating Cornelia with his Geass C.C becomes aware of this and warns Lelouch. the 2 then leave Tokyo for Kaminejima Island. During this time we see a shot of V.V and Nunnally at the Sword of Akasha with V.V looking board.

2 Years Later when Lelouch had regained his memories Nunnally appears again, appointed as Viceroy of Area 11.

Where was Nunnally that entire time? was she confined by the Geass Order (as V.V was it's director)? was Nunnally aware or made aware of what happened to her?

Comment: *was she confined by the Geass Order* -- it is very likely. *was Nunnally aware or made aware of what happened to her* -- i don't think so. As her father also knows her whereabout (the fact that she was kidnapped by V.V.) it must be her father that deals with her later, as later she will be appointed as Viceroy.

Comment: Nunnally is aboard of Schneizel ship.

Answer (score 1):

It's never explicitly stated where exactly, but before she traveled to Area 11 to become viceroy, she was in Britannia (her plane departed from the California base).
It's most natural to assume she was with the rest of her family in the capital Pendragon until she left in Turn 6